# Add a JAR to WEB-INF\lib in Grails Portlets

Tags: grails, jar, dependencies, portlet, war

I'm using the Grails Porlets Plugin, and the generated portlet doesn't deploy because it needs commons-logging.jar, adding it manually to WEB-INF\lib in the generated portlet with 'grails war' solves the problem.

How can I do to automatically add this dependency to WEB-INF\lib every time I generate a new version of the portlet without having to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure commons-logging.jar as a dependency of your application in [BuildConfig.groovy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7%20Dependency%20Resolution). You'll need to add something like the following:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your libs in the *appname*\lib-folder it should be included automatically in you war-file.

Comment: If you do this you're bypassing Grails' dependency resolution, which is inadvisable